# How to detect unexpanded or missing value properties in Maven?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, properties-file

I'm configuring a web app to use Maven filtering to expand property placeholders in configuration files for different environments.

Is there a way to detect if any property hasn't been expanded in the filter files, i.e. if I could end up with `myprop=${customvalue}` at some stage before deployment?